# Sql execution speed very slow

Tags: sql, for-loop

I have for loop and within that loop I have used INSERT INTO command for 75000+ values. when i am running it consumes more time. how can I improve insertion speed,...

thanks in advance...
rgs
tharindu

Comment: "when i am running it consumes more time." More than what?

Comment: And tell us which DBMS you are using

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name: lol, I see a SQL question and imemediately assume SQL Server!! :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: And I immediately dismissed it when I saw `for-loop`. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server (was not specified): Rather than many individual `INSERT` calls, use a Bulk method such as

- [`SQLBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)
- [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)
- [bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Comment: I am using WAMP and have tables called master and master_break.. master table have fieds called start_number and no_of_items.

So I need to get start_number and no_of_items from master table and genarate posible numbers... 

ex:start_number = 45620
    no_of_items = 5

Comment: @tharindu: that's really interesting. what were you expecting me to do with that information?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a loop with 75k inserts, you're doing it wrong

Based on your comments, you need something to gererate rows for you.

```
;WITH cNumbers AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.id) - 1 AS rownum
    FROM sys.columns c CROSS JOIN start_number c2 CROSS JOIN start_number c3
)
SELECT
    c.rownum + m.start_number
FROM
    mastertable m
    CROSS JOIN
    cNumbers c
WHERE
    c.rownum <= no_of_items
```

There are better ways to generate rows but this will be better then looping 75k times.

Edit: the same idea applies to most RDBMS except MySQL which doesn't have Windowing functions...
  in which case I'd have a Numbers table filled with 1-100000 for examplke

Comment: he's using MySQL it would seem

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to write the data to insert to file, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE`in mysql to load it in batch. It should speed things up considerably compared to having 75000 separate inserts.