# how to improve sql INSERT INTO speed

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql execution speed very slow…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535304/sql-execution-speed-very-slow)

I am using WAMP and have tables called master and master_break. master table have fields called start_number and no_of_items.

So I need to get start_number and no_of_items from master table and generate possible numbers.

ex:

```
start_number = 45620;
no_of_items = 5;
```

Then I need to INSERT 45620,45621,45622,45623,45624 to master_break table. My master table produces over 75000 values. When I am running INSERT INTO always going out maximum_execution_time. How can I improve the insertion speed?

Comment: You should show us how you are inserting the items as you may have a problem in that code.

Comment: And tell us if this is a one time operation or does it need to be repeated (weekly, daily, hourly). Further, if you could tell us *why* you think you need this, we might come up with better solutions. I for one can't really think of a good reason for such a design.

Comment: Also, you might want to write a Stored Procedure to do it directly on the MySQL-Database rather then with a loop in (?)PHP.

Comment: Why not just use an autoincrement field in mysql instead of apparently trying to simulate one in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can improve MySQL insert speed by:

- Using MySQL multipe insert - e.g. `INSERT INTO tableName (col1) VALUES (a) , (b) , (c)`
- Disabling indexes, triggers for the insert (if practical)
- Using transactions.
- If you're calling inserts in a loop client-side, make sure you're not setting the query command text over-and-over. Set it once using parameters for the values, and then only change the parameter values each time through.

Comment: This is my PHP code
$Q=mysql_query("SELECT case_number,boxes FROM master");
 while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($Q))
 
 {
  
    $s=trim($arr['case_number']);
   
    $noc=trim($arr['boxes']) ;
   
    $e=($s+$noc-1);
 
 
  for($x=$s;$s<=$e;$s++)
   {
  
   
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO master_break (case_number) VALUES('$s')");
    
     $x++;
     
      
    
    
  }
    
  }